# Looping through query results and call a function for each - function contains sleep command

Tags: php

Bit of an odd one and I don't know if I am just over complicating the matter in my head. I have a query that will return a few results and a function that goes through a for loop and sleeps for 10 seconds at the end of every iteration.

What I need to do is loop through the query result calling this function for all the results. With the sleep in there, I believe it will only process the second query result when the for loop has finished for the first one. Does this make sense? i.e

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) 
{
  myFunctionThatCallsSleep6Times($row['Id']);
}
```

So the second result will only get called after the first result has finished but I need to start this function for each of the results at the same time.

Sorry if I am being unclear and thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "at the same time". Do you want to run the function but prevent it from sleeping or do you need real parallel execution of the function?

Comment: Well, PHP does not support multi-threading programming.
You can just process each row with the function without sleep and call sleep at the end. For small set of data, it will be in instant

Comment: I guess parallel execution. I need each function to sleep. BUT, I need the function to be called for all the query results in parallel.

Comment: @Radoslav: The sleep needs to happen as I am retrieving a log file from a server and it can only be captured every 10 seconds.

Comment: Is it not possible to move the sleep call to outside the while loop? Otherwise the sleep will indeed pause the PHP's execution and only process the second query afterwards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I have restructured my code so that the query is done inside the for loop that contains the sleep command. So it loops through all the results per sleep.